# Out Of Memory React

Tags: reactjs, textarea

Saludos espero me ayuden con este problema, lo que sucede es que cuando intento pegar una cantidad de caracteres muy extensa en un textarea el navegador se queda sin memoria y se cae la aplicación en React, habría alguna forma de manejar esta excepcion en React, la única solución que se me ocurre es poner un maxLength en el textarea, si es el caso debo capturar cuando el usuario ingresa muchos caracteres y mostrarle un mensaje, y no sé la cantidad máxima de caracteres que permite un textarea muchas gracias de antemano, he intentando algunas cosas pero no he conseguido.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Buenas tardes/noches, el máximo de caracteres default del textarea es de 524,288, técnicamente podrías insertar una novela allí. Estás superando ese número de caracteres?.
En ese caso te sugiero leer [ask], y quizás lo ideal sería que subas el código mínimo verificable para poder hacer las pruebas pertinentes y ayudarte en el menor tiempo posible.

Comment: muchas gracias ese era el dato que necesitaba, para poder ejecutar un acción.

Comment: Me alegro mucho de que haya sido útil, quedo a las órdenes.